# Access generic types of an object at runtime

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I know how to access generic types of fields using reflection: Just check if `field.getGenericType() instanceof ParameterizedType`.

But how can one check the same for an arbitrary object, not knowing where it was declared?

Comment: Doesn't type erasure kind of preclude this possibility?

Comment: The problem is: `getGenericType()` is a method of `Field` and cannot be applied to any `Object`...

Answer (score 2):

Generics apply to variable declarations, method return types, etc., not objects per-se.  You can determine whether the `Class` of a particular object uses generics via `myObj.getClass().getTypeParameters()` but you can't determine what values of those type parameters the specific object instance was created with.

Answer (score 2):

Objects do not store generic information *per se*, so the bytecode generated for `new ArrayList<Integer>()` is exactly the same as the one for `new ArrayList<String>()`. I mean *exactly*. This is what is called *type erasure* of Java generics. They are just desugared to `new ArrayList()`.

But, in almost all other situations, type parameters are retained, like field/parameter/return type declarations. One of the cases that is retained and *not* erased is the super class of a class. So if you create a class that extends `ArrayList<String>` you can access that information at runtime.

But this seems overkill, doesn't it? A new class that extends `ArrayList<String>` and another one that extends `ArrayList<String>`, etc. seems impractical. Anonymous inner classes can make this much easier. So, if you want to keep the generic information, you just do `new ArrayList<String>() {}` instead of `new ArrayList<String>()`. You can call `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()` on the created object to get the generic info.

Comment: I'm not trying to keeping them on my own, but to restore generic types of users after transporting objects in a serialized form... I guess that's not possible in a proper way. One best-effort approach would be to check if a class uses generic types, and if so, check if there are fields inside using them. Using an instance and such fields, the used generic type could be reconstructed. But for my work, this is kind of an overkill I guess...

Comment: +1: this is the same technique used by [Guava's `TypeToken`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html).

Comment: @IanRoberts Yes Guava uses the same technique. I believe it was Neal Gafter who originally blogged about this pattern in 2006. That he called the [Super Type Tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.de/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) pattern. It is a bit under-appreciated in the Java community in my opinion.